# Difference between eval and window.json.parse for a dealing with a responseText?

Tags: javascript, responsetext

I have the following code at hand

**var finalCompleteData = eval("("+jsonresponse.responseText+")");**

When I used this, I received a security flaw error in Fortify saying that it might lead to Javascript Hacking. So, I changed it to

**var finalCompleteData = window.json.parse(jsonresponse.responseText);**

For this, Fortify did not show the error. What the window.json.parse method do ?

Can you please explain. Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`eval` will execute any JavaScript code which it is supposed to evaluate, and it evaluates with the highest level of security.  This means that if your response text returns non-json code, but valid javascript, the `eval` will execute it.  The sky is the limit with this, it can add new functions, change variables, redirect the page.

With `window.json.parse` only json will be evaluated, so the risk of rogue code getting entered is much much less.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer .. I actually wanted to mitigate the chances of non-JSON entry into my code .. So, thinking of using $.parseJSON instead of window.json.parse. Will that be fine ?

Answer (score 1):

eval is able to run any kind of javascript code - not just simple objects/arrays as JSON.parse would (it examines the contents - validating json). For this reason eval should be avoided in places where you cannot guarantee the input.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, `eval` will execute any valid JavaScript code. Thus the following would cause an alert:

```
var jsObject = eval("alert('blah')");
```

You're essentially trusting any input from a given source, which is not safe in general. A malicious user could take advantage of the eval and execute harmful JavaScript.

`JSON.parse`, however, will only return successfully if the string passed in is valid JSON:

```
// gives "SyntaxError: JSON.parse"
var jsObject = JSON.parse("alert('blah')");
```

Thus it's not executing just anything it's given the way `eval` is.